# How to linkup API in API manager with interface deployed in Cloud Hub?

Tags: api, mule

I have an API deployed in API Manager, deployed one interface in cloud hub with API auto discover option.

In API manager, i gave cloudhub link as implementation url. so i thought both are linked up.

But when i apply SLA tier to API it is not getting applied. is there anything need to be done ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please first apply Auto discovery properly on the app. Create one API in the API manager. copy API ID into autodiscover configuration in the app. please find below link for details explanation.

[Auto discovery article from dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/autodiscovery-in-anypoint-platform)